# 2D liquid as lightsource

Tags: c++, glsl, sfml

I'm making a 2D game with dynamic shading using normal maps and i've been working on liquid simulation using circular rigidbodies and a blur-like effect to generate a heightmap from which i generate both my diffuse and normal map. It's been working great for a level with water in it, but now i want to create a level with lava in it and that has some more requirements and I'm struggling with finding a way to make it work as a lightsource with a specified radius.

Here's a picture of what the liquid looks like when rigidbodies are shown for reference:

[image]

I've tried to give every "drop" its own lightsource, but this makes for way too much data sent to the GPU since there are 200 drops in a very small space where I'm trying to do this. I also tried to make a lightsource that took all the center positions and did the same thing basically, this took away a lot of extra information (since the radius, color and intensity of the light is the same across the board), but it's still too slow. It's not completely out of the question to try and reduce the amount of drops, but i'd like to do this as a last resort only.

Comment: In general the complexity of shading is in the order of `(number of light sources that may illuminate the fragment) * (number of fragments to shade)`. Even if you eliminate most of the properties and are left with just position data for each ones, you still have individual light sources to account for. Simplifying the light sources doesn't help much. You have to reduce how many you have or use non-point light sources (which gets much more complicated!).

Comment: You could consider a lighting map, where for every position (within a certain resolution) you count how many lava particles there are and use that as the "lava" light source component in your shading. You might get away with only updating the map when lava moves from one "cell" of your map to another.

Comment: What about deferred rendering? It should work here as well, and then 200 lights isn't that much.

Comment: Deferred rendering looks really interesting! I'm on a pretty tight deadline right now so I'll start finishing up as much as possible on the rest of the game and then I'll see if i have the time to make big changes like that before said deadline or if I'll have to just change the level. Thanks a lot!